# is it possible to put a customize gtkwidget in a gtktreeview?

Tags: qt, gtk

I'm learning GTK+ in this moment (after Qt) just to know what is possible with it thus Qt is for digia. Put a custom widget in a QListWidget is possible so I want to know if it is possible to do something like that using GTK+. An example of this widget could be one pixmap, one label and one button all in the same Cell and layout with a container like Gtktable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.  You just need a "custom cell renderer":

- http://scentric.net/tutorial/ch-treeview.html
- http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/html/tutorials/tutorials.treeview.view.html

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand this function: gtk_cell_renderer_get_size (). what is the widget pointer parameter in this function and the cell_area parameter. I think that "widget" is a pointer to the gtktreeview and that cell_area is one area portion of this gtktreeview to render a cell in the gtktreeviewcolumn but in this case, I don't understand the why of this function because gdkrectangle structure has in it his width and his height.